# How To make the slideshow move up when the listview moves up flutter

Tags: flutter

I have one page in that page there are one Slideshow and one listview with Lazy Loading I need when user move the list to up the part of Slideshow disappears or hide.

this image example what I try to do:

example-1
[enter link description here](https://i.imgur.com/fNMVIGJ.gif)

example-2
[image]

page code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<dynamic> _data = [];

  int _page = 1;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchData();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        _fetchData();
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    if (_isLoading) return;

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=$_page&_limit=20'));

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
      _data.addAll(json.decode(response.body));
      _page++;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Lazy Loading ListView with Slideshow'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(flex:1,child: SlidrShow()),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: _data.length + 1,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index == _data.length) {
                  if (_isLoading) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return SizedBox.shrink();
                  }
                } else {
                  final item = _data[index];

                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item['title']),
                    subtitle: Text(item['body']),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }}
```

what I have to add to my code to make that.
I tried for a long time but it didn't work with me.
hele me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality using `SliverAppBar` By making it's **floating** , **pinned** & **snap** fields to **True**.

Example :-

```
  class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          const SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            snap: true,
            floating: true,
            expandedHeight: 160.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
              background: FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```